# May Algebraic Geometry be appropriate for me?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, category-theory

I am a student of Mathematics who have to choose its area of specialization.
I am trying to obtain as more information as possible, by asking a lot of questions to more experienced people, trying to have enough idea to make the right choice (or something really near).
I should be very glad to anyone who should choose to spend a part of its time to help a poor student lost in its sea of possibilities :-)

My first (vague) question simply is:

- why have you chosen to specialize exactly in the area X, instead of something different? What do you think about the remaining area? Let's assume that a student loves areas A,B,C in the same way...how could he choose the most appropriate? Do you have some general advice?

My second question is instead much more specific:

- Let's assume that I love Category Theory and Homological Algebra, but I *hate* polynomials. Could be a wise idea to proceed towards Algebraic Geometry?  I see that the by an elementary point of view, it seems to be strongly related to the solution of systems of polynomials (a problem in which I am not so interested), but on the other hand it proceed towards a good level of abstraction and use of CT. Is this level again related to polynomials, or are they "abandoned"?

**Edit**
My question has been put on "on hold" because considered too subjective.
I disagree, and suspect that it has been misunderstood . More precisely, my question could be reformulated as follows:

> I know that polynomials play a key role for motivating the basic development of Algebraic Geometry. Are they still present/fundamental in the development/understanding of *modern* algebraic geometry, or are they maybe "obsolete" and "abandoned" in favor of more advanced ideas from Category Theory/some related area?

Thank you in advance for any help!!!
Cheers!

Ps: I am not a native English speaker, consequently my apologies for some probably grammar-related errors.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid polynomials in general but I'm open to correction. You might find that you enjoy certain things about them if they help you prove something you are interested in?

Comment: I tell you what not in just in mathematics, if you like something you should know why you like it. If you hate it, why it is putting you out... and this reason gives some valuable information to you about yourself.

Comment: One often hears young math students saying they *dislike X* while contemplating future studies.  At best, this shows immaturity and lack of professionalism (I have never heard a physician who exclusively specializes in one part of the body say that they hate another part).  Taken as a long-term state: failure in mathematics is virtually guaranteed if you cultivate an active dislike of a broad and/or basic part of mathematics.  Since you asked: doing algebraic geometry with a hatred of polynomials is indeed ridiculous...assuming you are using "hate" in anything like the standard way.

Comment: Dear @PeteL.Clark, thank you for your help! I completely agree with you!!! This is exactly the key of my problems in choosing an area of specialization, because almost all my friends behaves as you describe and I disagree with them. Finally, thank you for you interest and for your answer about polynomials...yes, maybe "hate" is a bit too strong, but surely I don't like and I prefer to avoid them as more as possible :-)
 Cheers Ps: do you mind having a look to my other question?
(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1407160/the-specialization-dilemma).

Comment: "but surely I don't like and I prefer to avoid them as more as possible" What I'm trying to say is that to a mathematician, that sounds like a would-be writer averring that he will try to avoid using the letter "g" as much as possible.  If you agree that your perspective lacks professional maturity, I would recommend that you talk to people who are more professionally mature, i.e., the faculty in your department.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Saying “sounds like a would-be writer averring that he we try to avoud isng the letter “g” as much as possible” – isn’t that a bit overstating it a bit? This is meant as a real question, because I’m not a professional mathematician, but I don’t see the analogy “letters – concepts” at all: 1) Words are used by writers as *material*, concepts are used by mathematicians as *tools*, and letters are “submaterial”, writers actually don’t use letters. 2) you cannot introduce new letters to better express yourself as a writer, letters are sort of determined once and for all, and …

Comment: … 3) letters all share the same functionality, 4) concepts do come with a way to think, and 5) disliking concepts (like zero, imaginary numbers, set theory, general nonsense) has been done by professional mathematicians. Therefore, to me it doesn’t seem to be that much immature to hate a certain mathematical concept as a mathematician. Is it yet?

Comment: By the way, Majin-Bu, out of curiosity: What happens if you think of the polynomial ring $R[X]$ of a commutative ring $R$ as the free commutative $R$-algebra over $X$? Like viewing polynomials as the left adjoint $R[•]\colon \mathrm{Set} → R\mathrm{-CAlg}$ to the forgetful functor?

Comment: I am very grateful for your comments :-)
Yes, being still a student without a huge experience, my level of "professional maturity is still low", and this is the first reason for which I am very glad to compare my opinions with other people.
During my studies I have seen polynomials essentially in three courses: Galois Theory, Introduction to number Theory and Commutative Algebra, and I didn't enjoy them particularly. Probably the reasons are three:

Comment: (1) they always carried with them a lot of (boring, by my point of view) computations...I will never forget so may afternoon spent in calculating the spectrum of so many polynomial rings with quotients;
(2) They are not so abstract;
(3) After a lot of efforts in understanding the pure theorems, proofs and ideas, I failed a couple of exams because I did some computation wrong.

Comment: These two events discouraged me a lot in proceeding towards the area of Algebra. Near the end of the last year, I did an introductory course on Category theory...and it was amazing. Furthermore...polynomials don't inspire me, conversely smooth manifolds or abstract integration theory do it...
Dear @k.stm ...I have to say that I have never viewed polynomials as a functor as you say...it can be an enlightenment... :-)

Comment: @k.stm: I did not mean to suggest an *ontological* analogy between "g" and polynomials.  Rather the point is that for a journeyman to avoid either one has similar effects: a severe and artificial limitation on their work.  Your examples of avoidance of zero and imaginary numbers are hundreds of years old; no contemporary mathematician could possibly get away with that.  Polynomials are also not a good analogy to set theory and category theory because the latter do not come up in everyone's mathematical training, whereas the former are ubiquitous.

Comment: But since you ask, in my opinion it is professionally immature to profess a blanket dislike for a mathematical concept.  There is no positive effect to this.  All one could mean is that a certain concept has (i) not yet been absorbed or understood or (ii) has been and has not been found to be directly useful in one's work.  "I don't like category theory" is a callow sentiment no matter who says it.  Yes, professional mathematicians can be callow and have other negative qualities and succeed in spite of them.  This makes it more important to point out the callowness to young people.

Comment: Finally, although there are branches of mathematics in which an eccentric hatred of polynomials could be relatively harmless, the OP has mentioned an interest in **algebraic geometry**, i.e., the branch of mathematics in which polynomials are the most basic object.  The OP hopes that after enough study and abstraction algebraic geometry will eventually not be concerned with these distasteful objects, and the main point of my comment was to offer a professional perspective: no way.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark The differences in role between letters and concepts I mentioned were supposed to show that hating certain letters is fundamentally und utterly different to hating certain concepts.

Comment: @k.stm: Okay, perhaps the analogy was not very good.

Comment: Dear @PeteL.Clark, I think you have slightly misunderstood my hatred for polynomials, or maybe my words have been too much exaggerated. To encounter a polynomial during my studies is not seen by myself as a tragedy, or something insurmountable, but simply I should prefer to work with different objects...for tastes, they just don't say "nothing" to my mind (conversely, some facts about set theory, differential geometry or measure theory do).
Being aware that polynomials have played a key role in AG, I was just curious to know if they continue to be so important in the modern theory.

Comment: I am curious abut this fact because:
(1) I am becoming interested in Category Theory, and I should be glad to specialize in a branch where CT strongly used;
(2) I have opened some modern books on Algebraic Geometry, and I have not seen any polynomials except for some example in the first chapter/s;
(3) I know that CT is used in AG.
As a consequence of these points, I was considering the idea to specialize in AG...nothing more.

Comment: Dear @PeteL.Clark, I trust you. I think you are right, and I probably have to win my psychological trouble with polynomials. I have done an "agreement with myself": I will dedicate the next ten days in trying to defeat my hatred for polynomials...I will write here my progress :-)
Have a nice day!!!
Cheers
Ps: thank you for everyone who helped my with his/her comment ;-)